# Reactでエラー　TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function

Tags: node.js, webpack, react-native, google-cloud-storage

Google Cloud Platform(GCP)でwebアプリを作っています。
webアプリからGCP Storageに画像をアップロードするようなものを作りたく、
[Node.jsからCloud Storageを利用(入門)](https://qiita.com/NOGU626/items/1af991b1757988b6cee6)などを参考にしているのですが、

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

この一文で下記のエラーが出てしまいます。

```
 #### Uncaught TypeError: The "original" argument must be of type Function
    at promisify (util.js:601:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/get-stream/index.js (index.js:7:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.< anonymous > (file.js:20:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/file.js (file.js:3264:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.< anonymous > (bucket.js:31:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js (bucket.js:3323:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/index.js (index.js:16:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Module.< anonymous > (Game.jsx:163:1)
    at Module../src/Home/Home.jsx (Home.jsx:184:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Module.<anonymous> (useChat.js:109:1)
    at Module../src/index.jsx (index.jsx:108:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at fn (bootstrap:150:1)
    at Object.1 (index.jsx:108:1)
    at __ webpack_require __ (bootstrap:851:1)
    at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45:1)
    at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32:1)
    at main.chunk.js:1:77
```

すでに、dockerfileのnode versionを変えたり、nodeのversionを変更して試しました。

また、requireに代わり

```
import {Storage} from '@google-cloud/storage';
import * as Storage from '@google-cloud/storage';
```

を試してみましたが、これらも同じエラーが出ます。

具体的にどのようなエラーか、何が原因なのかを教えていただけないでしょうか？

追記2022/2/18
行ったことは下記2点で、2でエラーが出ています。

1. yarn add '@google-cloud/storage'
2. yarn start でブラウザーで動かしています。

環境：
windows10
node:v15.14.0
npm:7.7.6
react:17.0.2
@google-cloud/storage:^5.18.1

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　回答したい人が質問者さんの抱えている問題点を正確に把握できるように、どうやったらこの問題が再現できるかの手順を教えていただけないでしょうか。たとえば、このソースコードを元に何をしたらエラーメッセージが表示されるのかを質問文に書いていただけると、問題が再現しやすくなって助かります。質問文はいつでも [edit] して内容を追記できますので、どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: より具体的に知りたいのは、質問者さんはこのコードをブラウザー上で実行しようとしていますか？　それともサーバー上の node コマンドを使って実行しようとしていますか？　というのも https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1725 によるとブラウザー上での実行はサポートされていません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！すみません、通知が来ず気づきませんでした。編集して追記しました。ブラウザ上での実行がサポートされていることは知りませんでした。私が参考にしたQiitaの記事はサーバー上で実行していることになるのですか？

Comment: はい、node コマンドを使って Node.js 製のサーバーアプリケーションとして実行することが想定されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！サーバーで動かすようにやってみます！